# Why does the 'Health' iOS package for Flutter not collect my information on my actual iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter

I am trying to create a Health app and I started using my actual iPhone as a simulator for the app. I have got it connected to the project but there is one problem. I have a feature that collects and displays health features from the user's local 'Health' app. It worked on the iOS simulator when I first started testing my app but it doesn't seem to collect it when I use the app on my actual iPhone. Moreover, it asks for permissions on the simulator but it doesn't seem to do so on my iPhone.

Here is the relevant code:

```
var types = [
    HealthDataType.ACTIVE_ENERGY_BURNED,
    HealthDataType.STEPS,
  ];

  var permissions = [
    HealthDataAccess.READ,
    HealthDataAccess.READ,
  ];

void getCaloriesBurned() async {
    var now = DateTime.now();
    var midnight = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day);
    var strings = [];

    List<HealthDataPoint> healthData =
        await health.getHealthDataFromTypes(midnight, now, [types[0]]);

    await health.requestAuthorization(types, permissions: permissions);

    if (healthData.isEmpty) {
      showBanner('No data available. Log some calories into the Health app!');
      return;
    }

    for (var dataPoint in healthData) {
      strings.add(dataPoint.value.toString());
    }

    for (var string in strings) {
      caloriesBurned += double.parse(string).round();
    }

    await addCaloriesBurnedToFirestore(caloriesBurned);

    setState(() {
      caloriesBurned = caloriesBurned;
    });
  }

getSteps() async {
    var now = DateTime.now();
    var midnight = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day);

    int? healthData = await health.getTotalStepsInInterval(midnight, now);

    await health.requestAuthorization(types, permissions: permissions);

    if (healthData != null) {
      setState(() {
        totalSteps = healthData.toDouble().round();
      });
      await addStepsToFirestore(totalSteps);
    } else {}
  }

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    health.requestAuthorization(types);
    getSteps();
    getCaloriesBurned();
    fetchPreviousSteps();
    fetchPreviousCalories();
  }
```

Let me know if you any more information. Thanks once again.

Here are screenshots of my iPhone's permissions too:
[image]
[image]

I thought it would work exactly as the Simulator would, but it does not.